# A $p$-subgroup of a finite group is either a Sylow $p$-subgroup or properly contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup of its normalizer

Tags: finite-groups, sylow-theory

This exercice is from Aschbacher's book "Finite group theory".

I am not asking for a complete solution, just for a hint.

Here is a partial solution, when the ambient group $G$ is a $p$-group.
If $X$ is a subgroup contradicting the exercise, then $X < G$ and $X = N_G(X)$.
However, one can easily that this cannot happen in a $p$-group (by induction on the order of $G$).

Comment: This theorem is related to the fact that if $p^n$ divides $|G|$ then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^n$.

Comment: Can you use Sylow theorems?

Comment: @JustinBenfield OK. Let $X$ be a $p$-subgroup of $G$ which is not a $p$-Sylow. Then I claim that there is a $p$-subgroup $Y \leq G$ such that $[Y:X] = p$ (this is the part I am not sure of). Then we prove that $X$ is normal in $Y$, which implies that $N_G(Y) \leq N_G(X)$. Thus $X \leq Y \leq N_G(X)$, which implies that $X$ is not a $p$-Sylow of $N_G(X)$. Is this true?

Comment: @vizietto I think you are right, and remember: a finite $\;p\,-$ subgroup **always** has *normal* subgroups of any order dividing its order.

Comment: There indeed such a $Y$ by $X$ not $p$-Sylow ($X$ not $p$-Sylow implies that it's order is not the maximum power of $p$ that divides order of $G$, hence there is a larger $p$-subgroup containing it because every $p$-subgroup is contained in some $p$-Sylow subgroup).

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily seen by applying the following lemma.

**Lemma** Let $P$ be a $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then $$P \in Syl_p(G) \iff P \in Syl_p(N_G(P)).$$
**Proof** If $P \in Syl_p(G)$, then, since $P \subseteq N_G(P)$, we obviously have $P \in Syl_p(N_G(P))$. So assume $P \in Syl_p(N_G(P))$. Then $|N_G(P):P|$ is not divisible by $p$. By Sylow Theory, we can find an $S \in Syl_p(G)$ with $P \subseteq S$. Hence $P \subseteq S \cap N_G(P)=N_S(P) \subseteq N_G(P)$. By comparing indices in these last inclusions and noting that $N_S(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup, we get $P=N_S(P)$. We now apply the *normalizers grow principle* (see I.M. Isaacs *Finite Group Theory*, Theorem 1.22 [here](http://mathhome.ir/my_doc/mathhome/Ketabkhane/Books/English%20Resources/l7/New%20Folder%20%283%29/__Finite_Group_Theory__Graduate_Studies_in_Mathematics__copy%28isaacs%29.pdf)): if $P \subsetneq S$, then we would have $P \subsetneq N_S(P)$. This is a contradiction, so $P=S \in Syl_p(G)$.

Now back to your/Aschbacher's problem: if $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, then we are done, If not, then by the Lemma, the $p$-subgroup $P$ is *not* a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$. But by Sylow Theory (applied to $N_G(P)$!) $P$ is contained and thus properly contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a finite group, $p$ a prime and $R$ a $p$-subgroup of G. Prove that either $R \in Syl_{p}(G)$ or $R$ is properly contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_{G}(R)$.

$\textbf{Proof.}$ The case when $R = 1$ is trivial. So, we may assume $R \neq 1$. Assume $R \notin Syl_{p}(G)$. Thus $p \ | \ |G:R|$. It suffices to show that $p \ | \ |N_{G}(R):R|$. Set $\Omega = \{Rg \ | g \in G\}$, i.e. the right cosets of $R$ in $G$. $G$ and therefore $R$ acts on $\Omega$ by translation. The point stabilizer of $Rg$ is $R^{g}$. Hence $$R\ \  \text{fixes} \ \ Rg \Leftrightarrow R \leq R^{g} \Leftrightarrow R = R^{g} \Leftrightarrow g \in N_{G}(R)$$ Thus $\Omega^{'} = \{Rg \ | g \in N_{G}(R)\}$ is exactly the fixed points of $\Omega$ under $R$'s action. Everything outside $\Omega^{'}$, $\Omega \setminus \Omega^{'}$, is a union of orbits of length divisible by $p$. Hence $$|G:R| = |N_{G}(R):R| \ \ \text{mod} \ \ p$$ Since $p \ | \ |G:R|$ it follows that $p \ | \ |N_{G}(R):R|$, and we are done.